# How to make call backs between Fragments of the same Ativity

Tags: android, callback, fragment

I have 4 tabs in an Activity.

Each of them is a Fragment. And every Fragment has a ListView.

So, if i change the ListView in Fragment, it must change the ListView in all other Fragments ie.., Tabs.

The problem i face is while creating the interface instance.

It takes it's own onClick() method.

In case i want a callback to the parent activity i could have done that by overriding **onAttach**. But how to make a callback to a Fragment?

**From Developers site:**

*Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for example to change the content based on a user event. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.*

So, make a callback to the Activity which in turn makes a callback to other fragments??

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple,all You need is steps below:

1) From `onClick` method in your first fragment make a function call of activity:

```
((IYourActivityInterface) getActivty()).activityMethod();
```

2) In your activity find fragment by tag or id and run it's method:

```
public void activityMethod(){
    Fragment tabFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("second_fragment");
    // or Fragment tabFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag);
    if (tabFragment!=null){
       ((IFragmentInterface) tabFragment).fragmentMethod();
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.)

Comment: This needs the **fragmentMethod()** to be static. But i don't want it to be static. Moreover if its static, i could have called it directly from other Fragments instead of going to the Parent activity and calling the fragmentMethod().

Comment: NO it's not. `findFragmentByTag(...)` returns you an instance of currently showed fragment with this TAG, so you can call non-static methods too. EDIT: Also this pattern is good enough because  `is done through the associated Activity`

Comment: Or you could, instead of findFragmentByTag, just keep a reference to the fragment when creating it. This way you wouldn't need to 'find' it every time you want to call it from activity.